# Orthogonal geodesic chords

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a connected Riemannian manifold with boundary, $n \geq 2$. A **chord** of $M$ is a non constant geodesic $c : [a,b] \to M$ with endpoints $c(a), c(b) \in \partial M$ but $c(t) \in \operatorname{int} M$ for $a < t < b$. Let

$$\ell = \ell(M,g) = \inf \{ \operatorname{length}(c) : c \text{ is a chord of } M \}.$$

Assuming that $M$ is compact, it it true that $\ell(M,g) > 0$? Is it achieved by a chord of $M$?

Now let

$$SC(M,g) = \{ \gamma : [0, \ell] \to M \text{ chord of } M \text{ of length } \ell(M,g) \}.$$

(SC stands for "shortest chords"). Does there exist $\gamma \in SC(M,g)$ which meets $\partial M$ orthogonally at the endpoints?

For instance, let $(M,g)$ be the upper hemisphere of the unit round sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then $\ell = \pi$ and every chord has the same length. In particular, through every point at the boundary there passes exactly one shortest chord which is orthogonal to the boundary.

Answer (score 1):

It is false that $\ell(M, g) > 0$ under these hypotheses. To see this, consider $(\mathbb{D}, g_{\mathbb{D}})$ to be the closed unit disk in the plane with the Euclidean metric. Taking nearly-vertical straight lines through the point $(1,0)$ gives a counter-example. The salient difference between this example and the half-sphere is that the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$ is concave, while the boundary of the half-sphere is a geodesic.